# zeromq with protobuf segmentation fault while parsing in c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am using zeromq with protobuf to send/recieve messages but code was crashing on receiver end with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error while parsing the received data.

`Scan` is my message.

**sender.cpp**

```
Scan proto_ls_msg;
proto_ls_msg.set_angle_min(0.0);
proto_ls_msg.set_angle_max(180.5);
std::string ls_msg_str;
proto_ls_msg.SerializeToString(&ls_msg_str);
zmq::message_t request (ls_msg_str.size());
memcpy (request.data(), ls_msg_str.c_str(),ls_msg_str.size());
socket.send (request);
```

**collector.cpp**

```
zmq::message_t recieved;
socket.recv (&recieved);
//thanks to πάντα ῥεῖ
std::string ls_msg_str((char*)recieved.data(),recieved.size()); 
Scan *pb_laser_msg_rcv;
pb_laser_msg_rcv->ParseFromString(ls_msg_str); // <--  Segmentation fault here
```

I tried different way of converting `zmq::message_t` to `std::string` but still it gives segmentation fault.

Edit update:

```
//std::string ls_msg_str((char*)recieved); 
  std::string ls_msg_str((char*)recieved.data(),recieved.size());
```

thanks.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but did you try ParseFromArray() and SerializeToArray() perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can't directly cast a `zmq::message_t` to a string. You should probably only use the `data` member to create the string.
Also the `recieved.data` is not `'\0'` terminated, so you would also need to pass the size when you construct the `ls_msg_str` instance:

```
std::string ls_msg_str((char*)recieved.data,recieved.size);
                                    // ^^^^          ^^^^
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I did that but still Segmentation fault while parsing.